# RANSAC в MatLab

Tags: matlab

Есть задача. Необходимо добавить собственный код алгоритма RANSAC. Я попробывал, но програма выдает не правильный результат. Может кто подскажет, где я ошибся.

Входящие параметры – облако точек p из набора данных и следующие настройки:

`confidence` – достоверность результата в процентах;

`inlier_margin` – максимальное расстояние от точки до плоскости, при которой эта
точка считается «inlier» (в метрах);

`parameters.sigma1` – минимальное расстояние всех отобранных точек одна до
одной (в метрах);

Выходные параметры функции:
`a, b, c, d` – параметры плоскости определены из уравнения:

```
 ∙  +  ∙  +  ∙  +  = 0
```

`inliers` – логический (бинарный) массив 1×N, обозначающий точки облака как
"inliers". Содержит 1 для каждого inlier и 0 для outliers для соответствующей
позиции в массиве p.

Например, `inliers = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, ...]` означает, что точки из p с
номерами колонок 2, 5, 7, 8,... являются «inliers» и входят в рассчитанную плоскость

`k` – необходимое количество итераций для достижения достоверности результата
Дополнительно описания исходных параметров смотреть в комментариях к файлу.
Облако точек p – это массив (6×N, где N – количество точек в облаке), содержащее
следующие данные:

```
1. x – расстояние, метры
2. y – расстояние, метры
3. z – расстояние, метры
4. r – яркость пикселя (0-1)
5. g – яркость пикселя (0-1)
6. b – яркость пикселя (0-1)
```

Есть код - https://pastebin.com/deE4ZvAK

[image: Такой результат я получаю.... но это не верный результат.]